# Getting msg "could not write image: no such file or directory"

Tags: image

This suddenly started today when I attempted to save an image file (save as image).  I have tried different directories, different blend files, and still it will not save the file.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, found out it is not a blender problem but a Windows 10 setting.  I changed the Controlled Folder access in the windows security settings to on and that caused the problem.  Changed to off, and problem disappeared!