# File isn't saving. Saving problems

Tags: saving

I am trying to create a model, but there is something that says there is "no such file or directory". What do I do?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115447/getting-msg-could-not-write-image-no-such-file-or-directory